# How do i setup a connection between the iOS Devince and server to pass data

Tags: ios, json, connection

I really have no idea about where to start.

I need a place to store datas, coming from my application user's but how do i do?

The answer is server.

I have never had any experience with server side of any application, but now i do but i got no idea about where to start.

What do i need?Where should i start?I need to get data from the user and store them, i ll be sending notification (push) to the user based on the data i got.

for the moderators; please don't take this question as too broad.I really have no idea to begin with.

Comment: Take a look at Apple's "URL Loading System Programming Guide" for the iOS side of interacting with servers..

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways of doing this.

1. Online server/webhost.

You will first need to equip yourself with an online server to serve the purpose.

Secondly, you will have to take to make a MYSQL database on the online website/server host and create a PHP file. After doing this, you should pass the parameters/entered values in your IOS application to this PHP file on the server. The PHP file then runs to add these entries to the database.

You can then access these entries from the database from another PHP file which the other/same program connects to.

1. Dedicated home server

By this I mean, the computer at home is dedicated to serve the requests made from your IOS applications. Although the implementations remain the same, in this case you can use sockets to let the client application connect to your computer using your computer's public IP address. You can have a dedicated server application running on your PC to receive incoming requests and connections and create an instance of thread for each of them. And also, you would need a local database just like the previous method to store the data in case you need it for further use, else you could just parse the request and send a reply/message accordingly from the home server application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Man my advice for you would be to check Parse. This company was bought by Facebook and it's focused on create a server side integrated with your app using less effort(don't need to any web language to create a server). Check this out https://parse.com/

P.S.: There is a new API for iOS 8 called CloudKit. This might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is [Parse](https://parse.com/). It's free to use, and they have great iOS documentation. There's only a few steps to use it.

- [Create an account](https://www.parse.com/#signup)
- Go to [account keys](https://www.parse.com/account/keys) once you have an account and get ApplicationID and Client Key
- [Download the iOS SDK](https://parse.com/docs/downloads)
- Add a ton of frameworks to your XCode project (including the `Parse.framework` file you just got)

AudioToolbox.framework

CFNetwork.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

CoreLocation.framework

libz.1.1.3.dylib

MobileCoreServices.framework

QuartzCore.framework

Security.framework

StoreKit.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

- Register yourself for Parse `[Parse setApplicationId:@"MY_APPLICATION_ID" clientKey:@"MY_CLIENT_KEY"];`

Create and try to save an object!

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"MY_APPLICATION_ID" 
              clientKey:@"MY_CLIENT_KEY"];

PFObject *chicken = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Chicken"];
chicken[@"eggsLaid"] = @(23);
chicken[@"name"] = @"Sally";
[chicken saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Successfuly saved chicken: %@", chicken);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"There was an error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

- Finally, go to [your dashboard](https://www.parse.com/apps) and add the class `Chicken`, and the columns `eggsLaid` (as a number) and `name` (as a string).